# Power BI: How to create a slider that slices multiple fields without becoming hierarchical?

Tags: powerbi

I have a few different fields that are related: "total shares", "private shares", and "general shares". These are continuous fields (i.e., values can be 1,2,3,4,...).
Currently, I have a slider set up to slice "total shares" but I want it to slice all three of those fields at the same time. In essence, visuals shouldn't display shares above the sliced amount just because they're technically "private shares" and not "total shares", an issue we're currently facing.

I've tried simply adding the fields into the slicer, but then it becomes a drop down where we select which one should be filtered. That's not what we're looking for either.

Another thing I tried is this:

```
shares_aggregate = 
ALL(
    merged_data[general_shares],
    merged_data[private_shares],
    merged_data[shared_files_from_storage],
    merged_data[shared_files_total]
    )
```

From there I'd apply a filter to shares_aggregate. PowerBi doesn't accept this though, because apparently I'm misunderstanding how ALL works.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, and let me know if It solves your problem.

```
shares_aggregate =
UNION (
    DISTINCT ( merged_data[general_shares] ),
    DISTINCT ( merged_data[private_shares] ),
    DISTINCT ( merged_data[shared_files_from_storage] ),
    DISTINCT ( merged_data[shared_files_total] )
)
```